# Как сделать плавный переход картинок

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть такой слайдер хочу  чтобы он плавно менялся.Конечно вы скажите есть много библиотек пользуйся ими но нет я хочу создать что нибудь свое.(Я начинающий)
Заголовок##

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
}
```

```css
.slideshow {  /* для того чтобы не влез на враппер**/
 position: relative; 
 z-index: 0;
 background-size: cover;
}

.mySlides {
 width: 100%;
 height: 564px;
 transition: 0.5s;
 
}
.button  {
 z-index: 1;
  padding: 6px 16px;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}
.button:hover {
 opacity: 1;
 background-color: #fff;
}
.display-left {
 opacity: 0.6;
 position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 1%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0%,-50%)
} 
.display-right {
 opacity: 0.6;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 1%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 transform: translate(0%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0%,-50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
     <a href="#"><img class="mySlides"  src="http://cdn3-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/siberian-husky-dog-breed-pictures/siberian-husky-dog-breed-pictures-5.jpg"></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="mySlides"   src="https://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/breeds/43/large/f203d4de017100405882dbf7268613d6.jpg"></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="mySlides"   src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7a/Huskiesatrest.jpg/1200px-Huskiesatrest.jpg"></a>

     <button class="button display-right" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
       <button class="button display-left" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
   </div>
```

## ##

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смена кадров у вас происходит за счет `display:block/none`. Со стороны `css` это всегда резкое появление/исчезание, так как элемент либо есть либо нет. Попробуйте осуществить смену кадров за счет прозрачности:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.opacity = "0"; 
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.opacity = "1"; 
}
```

```css
.slideshow {  /* для того чтобы не влез на враппер**/
 position: relative; 
 z-index: 0;
 background-size: cover;
  height: 564px;
}

.mySlides {
 width: 100%;
 height: 564px;
 transition: 0.5s;
 position:absolute;
}
.button  {
 z-index: 1;
  padding: 6px 16px;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}
.button:hover {
 opacity: 1;
 background-color: #fff;
}
.display-left {
 opacity: 0.6;
 position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 1%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0%,-50%)
} 
.display-right {
 opacity: 0.6;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 1%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 transform: translate(0%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0%,-50%)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow">
     <a href="#"><img class="mySlides"  src="http://cdn3-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/siberian-husky-dog-breed-pictures/siberian-husky-dog-breed-pictures-5.jpg"></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="mySlides"   src="https://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/breeds/43/large/f203d4de017100405882dbf7268613d6.jpg"></a>
     <a href="#"><img class="mySlides"   src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7a/Huskiesatrest.jpg/1200px-Huskiesatrest.jpg"></a>

     <button class="button display-right" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
       <button class="button display-left" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
   </div>
```

Со стороны `js`, например в `jQuery`, есть целый набор функций с готовыми анимациями:

```
.hide()
.show()
.slideUp()
.slideDown()
.slideToggle()
.fadeIn()
.fadeOut()
.fadeTo()
.fadeToggle()
```

Comment: спасибо большое и дай бог здоровье